# Jinja syntax for YAML File

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I've been reading a lot about loops in python and JINJA but I've not found the right answer for my problem. I'm really new to programming so I must be missing something

I'hve got the following **YAML file**

```
CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4:
  - RANGES:
    - 10.193.130.240/28
    - 10.193.135.240/28
  - HOSTS:
    - 10.193.131.131
    - 10.196.180.5
```

I'd like to generate a template with those variables and if I print the variable in Ansible it shows like this:

**Printing Variable**

```
[{u'RANGES': [u'10.193.130.240/28', u'10.193.135.240/28']}, {u'HOSTS': [u'10.193.131.131', u'10.196.180.5']}]
```

I'm trying the following in the JINJA template with no success:

**JINJA TEMPLATE**

```
{% for list in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4 %}
  {% for ips in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4[list] %}      

    Statement1 {{RANGES_IPs}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for list in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4 %}
  {% for ips in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4[list] %}  

    Statement2 {{HOSTS_IPs}}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Ansible Error:** `"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element {u'RANGES': [u'10.193.130.240/28', u'10.193.135.240/28', u'10.183.64.240/28', u'10.183.60.240/28', u'10.183.106.240/28', u'10.36.12.240/28', u'10.128.64.240/28', u'10.44.12.240/28', u'10.213.12.240/28', u'10.111.64.240/28', u'10.193.80.240/28']}"}`

**Request:**
Can you please let me know the best way or the easiest way to properly get the value of the 2 lists (4 IPs). I will need to access the values on the "RANGES" and the "HOST" lists. The values on the "RANGES" List will be used on statement 1 and the values on the "HOSTS" list will be used on statement 2.

Something like this:

**Expected result**

```
statement1 10.193.130.240/28
statement1 10.193.135.240/28

statement2 10.193.131.131
statement2 10.196.180.5
```

Comment: something's missing here. Show us how you are running this- the command line and the play file, presumably.

Comment: @ryekayo, you almost never need the leading `---` in a YAML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can refactor you YAML data, change it like this:

```
CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4:
  RANGES:
    - 10.193.130.240/28
    - 10.193.135.240/28
  HOSTS:
    - 10.193.131.131
    - 10.196.180.5
```

This way `CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4` is a dictionary with two keys `RANGES` and `HOSTS`, which are lists of strings.

Then you can do this:

```
{% for r in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4['RANGES'] %}
    Statement1 {{ r }} 
{% endfor %}

{% for h in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4['HOSTS'] %}
    Statement2 {{ h }}
{% endfor %}
```

With your original data, you have a list `CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4` which contains dictionaries as it's elements and each dictionary has different key inside. You'll have to write a bit more complex template to process this structure.

Comment: That's brilliant Konstantin, that worked for me. I re-arranged my YAML and accessed the variables that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @konstantin-suvorov YAML refactoring you could do the following code, so it can be more Dynamic

```
{% for name, sublist in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4.items() %}
  List: {{ name}}
  {%for value in sublist %}
    Value: {value}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In case you can't change your YAML , base on the output you shown before

```
Printing Variable
[{u'RANGES': [u'10.193.130.240/28', u'10.193.135.240/28']}, {u'HOSTS': [u'10.193.131.131', u'10.196.180.5']}]
```

in this case the YAML is processed as an array , so you will need to walk the array first

```
{% for lists in CONT_PLANE_PROT_V4 %}
  {%for name, sublist in lists.items() %}
   List: {name}
    {%for value in sublist %}
       Value: {value}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i don't think {value} will work.  you need {{value}}